# P2 sites security strategy

Tags: p2, update-site

We have a p2 site, which we want to make available for our customers. But we do not want someone else to access it. What are the strategies for securing p2 sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your sites requiring username and password before accessing it.